# Sass Gulp task gets "TypeError: Object css/ has no method 'on'"

Tags: node.js, sass, gulp

I have a gulp task using the gulp-sass plugin which I based on one included in the plugin's [README](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/blob/b5cba0eaafd8a0162756c5b977fdc3e73ef3cff9/README.md):

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    gulp.src('app/sass/')
        .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe('app/css/');
});
```

But it always fails with:

```
TypeError: Object app/css/ has no method 'on'
    at Stream.pipe (stream.js:65:8)
    at Gulp.gulp.task.gulp.src.read (/app/gulpfile.js:114:10)
    at module.exports (/app/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/app/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/app/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (/app/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:134:8)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:129:20
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
```

What's going on here? You would think the example from a README would be valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The README was missing `gulp.dest` in the output directory. It works correctly with it added:

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    gulp.src('app/sass/')
        .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css/'));
});
```